# Is there a way to see which contacts are "VIPs" outside of Mail.app?

Tags: macos, contacts, mail.app

Obviously, with Mountain Lion, users may define VIPs in Apple’s Mail.app. I would like to see which contacts are marked as VIPs outside of Mail – for example in Contacts.app (smart list??), or in Terminal. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be listed here.

~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/VIPSenders.plist

```
defaults read ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/VIPSenders.plist Senders
```

I only know how to narrow it down to the nested names in applescript. But you can use the applescript from terminal.

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e "tell app \"System Events\" to (get value of property list item \"Name\" of property list items of property list item \"Senders\" of property list file  \"~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/VIPSenders.plist\") "
```

Comment: Very nice! This will do. If anyone knows how to directly read the nested values from the plist file: you are welcome!